# Java REST Client still connects to old host after the dynamic address of the host was moved to another host

Tags: java, linux, jersey

I'm developing a client and server system with the following characteristics:
Client and sever here are running on Linux.

There is a pair of redundant server hosts (used for hw survivability).
Each host has a fixed IP address.
There is also a floating IP address that is bounded to one host at a time.

During a transition the standby host unbinds the floating IP, then the newly active host binds to it.
The binding is done with the ifconfig up/down command.
An arping -U is used to let know to the switch that the MAC associated with the address has changed.

Both server hosts are connected to the same switch.

In this system hosts names (fqdn) are not used.

The server hosts are running 2 java processes and an erlang one.

The client has a permanent listening socket open on the erlang process,
and also communicate with the Java processes using an RMI interface and a REST interface.
The Jersey v 1.17 framework is used for REST.
All Java processes are running Java 1.6.

When a client connects to the active server using the floating address things are originally working fine.
At one point I force a switch of the servers. 
The former active host unbinds the floating address, and the former standby host binds to it.

Fun starts here.
Three different behaviors are seen depending on where the client is running.

- A) the client is running on a different network than the host
  (routing is needed to reach the server).
- B) the client is running on    the originally standby host (remember
  that both server hosts are on  ) the same network/switch).
- C- the client is running on the initially    active host.

B & C are use cases that are required.

Case A was the easiest to solve.
As soon as the address is unbounded I get a socket exception, that I can react to, from the connection to the erlang process.
Simply waiting a bit for the address to be bounded again and reconnecting fixes this.
The RMI interface is the same, doing a name lookup again returns stubs that point to the new active host 
(the stub points to the fixed address - I can live with that)
Then when I issue REST request they also get routed to the new active host.

Case B provides a slightly different error, and heartbeat plays a role in the detection of the change,
but the solution is the same.

The case that defies my understanding is case C.
In this case connection to the erlang process is properly moving from the local host, to the new active host.
The RMI name lookup is also done from the new host.

The REST calls however are returning data from the local host (former active host), instead of the new active host.
This conditions remains for a few minute  (often 3-4 minutes) then things fix themselves!
I worked very hard to try to figure this one out, testing, web digging, so far no luck.

I considered that this behavior could come from 3 places:

- OS (i.e. kernel tcp/ip handling)
- The Java VM or its standard libraries
- The Jersey libraries

I made many hypothesis:

- The Linux kernel-IP stack, is caching the connection and does not
  realize that the address has moved until the cache times out.   I
  tried various command to flush it; no go.   The fact that the
  connection to erlang and that the name lookup works, is leaning me to
  believe that the kernel does not create the issue here.
- I considered that there could be some privileged java to java things
  happening in the guts of Java or the VM.   The fact that the name
  lookup works, probably invalidates this as well.
- My last hypothesis is that Jersey is doing some kind of caching.
  The web is talking about Http connection pooling.   Actually that
  could be the pooling of HttpUrlConnection done by Java.  I tried to
  learn more about this but only found vague references.   However most
  information I got indicates that the socket should be opened and
  closed for each REST request.

By now I'm desperate and ready to consider any hypothesis 
;-)

Can anyone shed light on a mechanism that would continue to routes packets to the wrong hosts
after the address moved host.

What can we say about the fact that it appears to clear after 3 to 4 minutes.
What type of cache could this be.

Thank you all for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find more time to dig into this issue.

I made more searches on the references made by some about a socket pool being used by  the HttpUrlConnection instances.

One of the interesting link I found is:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html

It confirms that by default a pool of socket is kept for HTTP connections.
The underlying sockets are kept alive.

This means that while you use a new HttpUrlConnection instance per request,
You are likely to reuse an already open socket.
That makes the client more efficient, particularly if HTTPS is used.

In my case (use case C) Linux provides a socket that remains functional between two local processes,
even if the original IP address used to open it is gone.

This means that the previously open socket from the pool is now pointing to the wrong host.
(I.e. the local host is no longer associated with the address, a new host is).

That explains the behavior I saw (*finally!*).

The fix is easy.

The article from Oracle indicates that you can set the system property **http.keepAlive** 
to false (default being true).

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

This makes the system opening a new socket for each HTTP requests.
You loose on efficiency, but get a client that can survive an address move.
This was critical in my case (but is probably not a common situation).

The article also mention a few other things you can do to control the pool (e.g. its size).

An alternative approach could have been to send, on address switch, an HTTP HEAD with the meta data Connection set to close.
Getting this right is more tricky, but would preserved the effectiveness of the client most of the time.

I anyone has additional insights, please feel free to provide them.